# checking to ensure all values in a field are integers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, floating-point, integer

I have a column that is currently a floating-point number and I need to check if all the values in the column are integers. What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And to specifically find the records that are not integers...

```
SELECT * from yourtable WHERE col % 1 != 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE ceil(yourcolumn) != yourcolumn
```

If the count > 0 then there are non-integer values.